# How to transform XML structure with PHP: simpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, transform

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<product version="1.4" productId="{97550402-c98f-4b42-b7e7-521961e2700b}" groupId="ACER" codeId="NX.M81EX.080">
    <name>Notebook Acer Aspire XYZ</name>
    <vendor>Acer</vendor>
    <propertyGroup propertyGroupId="{3f2c48a7-b185-4fad-bd20-7d0c50502645}">
            <propertyGroupName>Product : Common</propertyGroupName>
            <property propertyId="2" type="Text" name="Part No.">
                    <value valueId="0">NX.M81EX.080</value>
            </property>
            <property propertyId="3" type="Text" name="Model No.">
                <value valueId="0">Acer XYZ</value>
            </property>
    </propertyGroup>
    <propertyGroup propertyGroupId="{869eec69-8f70-40ac-a41d-c8958d743ad3}">
            <propertyGroupName>Notebook</propertyGroupName>
            <property propertyId="2" type="Enum" name="CPU">
                    <value valueId="337">CPU XYZ</value>
            </property>
            <property propertyId="10" type="Enum" name="Graphics">
                    <value valueId="242">Graphics XYZ</value>
            </property>
            <property propertyId="5" type="Enum" name="RAM">
                    <value valueId="6">RAM XYZ</value>
            </property>
            <property propertyId="11" type="Enum" name="HDD">
                    <value valueId="34">HDD XYZ</value>
            </property>
    </propertyGroup>
    <file type="Datasheet" description="">http://www.site.com/xyz.pdf</file>
    <image type="other">http://www.site.com/abc.jpg</image>
    <image type="other">http://www.site.com/xyz.jpg</image>
</product>
```

I'm using PHP: simpleXMLElement and have to structure this XML to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed>
    <products>
        <product>
            <codeId>NX.M81EX.080</codeId>
            <name>Notebook Acer Aspire XYZ</name>
            <vendor>Acer</vendor>
            <model>Acer XYZ</model>
            <category>Notebook</category>
            <CPU>CPU XYZ</CPU>
            <graphics>Graphics XYZ</graphics>
            <RAM>RAM XYZ</RAM>
            <HDD>HDD XYZ</HDD>
            <datasheet>http://www.site.com/xyz.pdf</datasheet>
            <image>http://www.site.com/xyz.jpg</image>
        </product>
    </products>
</feed>
```

I'v tried several recursive functions but without success.
I retrieve the values of the property but cannot retrieve the property name.
Can you help me. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a XSLT stylesheet like this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="product">
        <feed>
            <products>
                <product>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </product>
            </products>
        </feed>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="name|vendor">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="propertyGroup">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="propertyGroupName = 'Product : Common'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="property" mode="common"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <category><xsl:value-of select="propertyGroupName"/></category>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="property"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="property" mode="common">
            <xsl:if test="@propertyId=2">
                <codeId><xsl:value-of select="."/></codeId>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@propertyId=1">
                <model><xsl:value-of select="."/></model>
            </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="property">
        <xsl:element name="{@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="file[@type='Datasheet']">
        <datasheet><xsl:value-of select="."/></datasheet>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="image">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*|text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will transform the data above into the result below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed>
   <products>
      <product>
         <name>Notebook Acer Aspire XYZ</name>
         <vendor>Acer</vendor>
         <codeId>NX.M81EX.080</codeId>
         <category>Notebook</category>
         <CPU>CPU XYZ</CPU>
         <Graphics>Graphics XYZ</Graphics>
         <RAM>RAM XYZ</RAM>
         <HDD>HDD XYZ</HDD>
         <datasheet>http://www.site.com/xyz.pdf</datasheet>
         <image>http://www.site.com/abc.jpg</image>
         <image>http://www.site.com/xyz.jpg</image>
      </product>
   </products>
</feed>
```

You can load the XSL stylesheet, your source XML and run the XSLT processor with:

```
$processor = new XsltProcessor();
$xsl = new DomDocument;
$xsl->load('stylesheet.xsl');
$processor->importStylesheet($xsl);

$source = new DomDocument;
$source->load('your-xml-file.xml');

$result = $processor->transformToXML($source));
```

You can edit the XSL and adapt it for a broader scope of source documents if necessary. Your source had two images, so the result produced two image tags. If you only want the last image, change the template match to `image[last()]`.